# Извлечь адрес и записать в строку

Tags: python, python-3.x, natasha

Есть следующий код:

```
from natasha import AddressExtractor
from natasha.markup import (
    show_markup_notebook as show_markup,
    format_json, show_json
)

example = "(08.11.1957 года рождения, уроженца Ростовской области,
г.Шахты, зарегистрированного по адресу: Ростовская область, г. Шахты,
ул. Гагарина, д.45, кв. 264, СНИЛС xxx-xxx-xx-xx, ИНН xxxxxxxxxxxx)"

extractor = AddressExtractor()

matches = extractor(example)
spans = [_.span for _ in matches]
facts = [_.fact.as_json for _ in matches]
show_markup(example, spans)
print(format_json(facts))
```

Получаю вывод:

```
(08.11.1957 года рождения, уроженца Ростовской области, г. Шахты,
 зарегистрированного по адресу:Ростовская область, г. Шахты,
 ул.Гагарина, д.45, кв. 264, СНИЛС xxx-xxx-xx-xx, ИНН xxxxxxxxxxxx)
[
  {
    "parts": [
      {
        "name": "Ростовская",
        "type": "область"
      },
      {
        "name": "Шахты",
        "type": "город"
      },
      {
        "name": "Гагарина",
        "type": "улица"
      },
      {
        "number": "45",
        "type": "дом"
      },
      {
        "number": "264",
        "type": "квартира"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Как мне получить строку с адресом, следующего вида:

```
"Ростовская область, г. Шахты, ул.Гагарина, д.45, кв. 264"
```

Comment: Извлечь откуда - из исходной строки или из готового джейсона?

Answer (score 2):

`spans` - это список границ срезов исходной строки. Берем первый элемент (считаем, что есть хотя бы одно совпадение), и используем его элементы как границы среза:

```
address = example[spans[0][0]:spans[0][1]]
# или address = example[slice(*spans[0])]
print(address)
```

Вывод:

```
Ростовская область, г. Шахты, ул. Гагарина, д.45, кв. 264
```

Что внутри списка spans:

```
print(spans)
# [[96, 153)]
print(type(spans[0]))
# yargy.token.Span
print(tuple(spans[0]))
# (96, 153)
print(spans[0][0], spans[0][1])
# 96 153
```

Видно, что это объект библиотеки [yargy](https://github.com/natasha/yargy), который по сути мало отличается от `tuple` (если не считать, что при выводе правую скобку отображает круглой, подчеркивая, что правая граница среза не входит в срез).

При использовании функции `show_markup` в jupyter найденные срезы отображаются поверх исходной строки:

[image: show_markup]